# PhpStorm: How to order html tag attributes?

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to order the html tag attributes in PhpStorm 2019.3?

Editor -> Code Style -> HTML -> Arrangement does have an attribute rule (empty), but I don't know how that works because when I reformat the code, the attributes (id, class, width, height, data) order doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can indeed be configured in **Code Style -> HTML -> Arrangement**: by default, attributes are sorted in alphabetical order, but you can delete the default rule and add your own, defining a custom order.

To get the attributes re-arranged, please use **Code | Rearrange Code** action, or make sure that **Rearrange Code** is enabled in **Reformat File** dialog to make this work on reformatting the file

[image]

Note that you can use **Code | Show Reformat file dialog** to edit the preferences

Comment: My problem is that the attributes are not sorted, even with the default rule in place and the "Rearrange code" option checked. I can't seem to figure it out. The rest of the code gets properly formatted, but the attributes order stays unchanged.

Comment: works for me; i'd suggest submitting a support ticket, providing a test project + your code style settings

Comment: There's a caveat. This only works if your file extension is ".html".

Comment: Note, this doesn't work for Laravel blade views (.blade.php files)...